# Monkey patch class methods

Tags: ruby, class, monkeypatching

I'm trying to do some monkey patching in [ActiveShipping UPS class](https://github.com/Shopify/active_shipping/blob/master/lib/active_shipping/shipping/carriers/ups.rb) .

I need to add a class level method (starting with `.self`), so here it's what I'm trying to do:

```
module ActiveMerchant
  module Shipping
    class UPS < Carrier
      def self.process_request(receiver, sender, packages, options = {})
        # some code
      end

      def regular_method
        "foobar"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Unfortunately when I'm trying to use it:

```
 ActiveMerchant::Shipping::UPS.process_request(receiver etc)
```

I get an error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `process_request' for ActiveMerchant::Shipping::UPS:Class
        from (irb):6
        from C:/Ruby19/bin/irb.bat:19:in `<main>'
```

There is no class method named `process_request` in original class.

In original UPS class provided in gem there is one static method defined `self.retry_safe = true`
and I can use it without errors.

I can also use `regular_method` after creating instance of UPS class.

**More details provided:**
I'm working with Rails 2.3 ( :-( ) and Ruby 1.9.2. I have no influce on environment.

Monkey patched code is under `plugins/my_plugin/lib/active_shipping/ext/carriers/ups.rb`

In /active_shipping I have file named extensions.rb in which i have:

```
require 'active_shipping'

require_relative 'ext/carriers'
require_relative 'ext/carriers/ups'
```

It deals with loading everything properly (I suppose basing on `regular_method` beheaviour from first chunk of code in my question).

I try to invoke process_request in one of my Controllers. This part is little tricky, beacuse i'm using sth like this:

`MyModel.courier_service.process_request(parameters)`

where `courier_service`, in this case holds the `ActiveMerchant::Shipping::UPS` class.

I'm still a newbie in Ruby and don't know what sort of details i should provide.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you want to do it in another way

File patch_classes.rb:

```
module ActiveMerchantExpand
  module Shipping
    module ClassMethods
      def self.process_request(receiver, sender, packages, options = {})
        # some code
      end
    end

    module InstanceMethods
      def regular_method
        "foobar"
      end
    end

    def self.included(receiver)
      receiver.extend         ClassMethods
      receiver.send :include, InstanceMethods
    end
  end
end
```

Then you have to load your class "ActiveMerchant::Shipping::UPS"
and after that you can attach your methods to your class via

```
Rails.configuration.to_prepare do
  require_dependency [[file for ActiveMerchant::Shipping::UPS]]
  require 'patch_classes' )
  ActiveMerchant::Shipping::UPS.send(:include, ::ActiveMerchantExpand::Shipping)
end
```

This is from rails plugin writing, i hope this helps.

regards tingel2k

Comment: I finally achieved my goal using simple monkey patching, but that's probably better way. It'll be on my mind when I find time to refactor that piece of code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you explicitly `require` file with your monkey patch? If you just put it under your app or lib path without requiring, it wouldn't load because constant `ActiveMerchant::Shipping::UPS` is defined in gem and it doesn't trigger dependency resolution mechanism.

Comment: From my understanding I think blid require the file correctly.  Otherwise he would not be able to call the regular_method as he said.

Comment: Yes, my file is loaded, just as Jing Li explained.

Comment: @blid, could you please provide more details.  Coz for me it looks weird, no typo, everything looks good.  And as far as I know, there is no way to prevent monkey patching.  BTW, you can also try ActiveMerchant::Shipping::UPS.singleton_methods to print out all class methods of UPS, of course in your case it would not contain process_request.

Comment: @Jing Li: I provided details as you asked, if I can add something more please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the details! Unfortunately I still can't see what goes wrong. You show `NoMethodError` exception coming from irb (rails console?), can you add full backtrace that comes from your controller? It should be in `log/development.log`. Did you test `regular_method` in both console and controller? Also, can you show how `MyModel.courier_service` gets set, and the contents of your plugin's `init.rb`: `plugins/my_plugin/init.rb` ?

Comment: I fixed or rather made a workaround:
I removed line `require_relative 'ext/carriers'` and just require all the files from /carriers by hand:
`require_relative ext/carriers/ups.rb  
require_relative ext/carriers/dhl.rb` I still don't know what is the reason behind this problem and I was also unable to reproduce this error at home env. I'll try again tomorrow at work.